# using 2 states to insert the records

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[Find the full code snippet here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-mclaren-9yvrcl?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const target = [
    { id: 16, word: "sixteen" },
    { id: 17, word: "seventeen" },
    { id: 18, word: "eighteen" }
  ];

  const initialState = {
    tid: "",
    name: ""
  };
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [raw, setRaw] = useState(initialState);

  function change() {
    setRaw((raw) => ({ ...raw, tid: target[count]?.id }));
    setRaw((raw) => ({ ...raw, name: target[count].word }));
    console.log(raw); //axios function to insert record
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={change}>Click</h1>
      <h2>Count : {count}</h2>
      <h2>
        Array: {target[count]?.id},{target[count].word}
      </h2>
      <h2>
        State Object : {raw.tid},{raw.name}
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am getting an array from database (declared sample `target` array in above code). Basically, I want to read the records and write the same to different table.

I am using `raw` state to store them. If you see above, it lags by `1`.
So, on

- Click #1: `initialState` is inserted
- Click #2: `target[0]` is inserted.

How to fix it so that on Click #1, `raw` is populated with `target[0]` data?

Comment: Can't you simply initialize `initialState` to `tid: target[0].id` and `name: target[0].word`?

Comment: I guess your question is more about keeping `count` in sync.  In your `change` function, use `const newCount = count + 1;` and then use that as an index, i.e. `target[newCount]` and then `setCount(newCount);`.

Comment: I think the main issue you hit is that the state in React doesn't take effect until the next render.

Comment: Yes. Thats the main issue. Wondering how others have solved it.
If I declare the tid: target[0].id in initial state then tid: target[0].id shows up and stays after Click#1 also

Answer (score 0):

[Follow the full code snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-mclaren-9yvrcl?file=/src/App.js:0-993)

the first useEffect was not closed so I comment on it and it works.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {


  // useEffect ( () => {


 const target = [
     { id: 16, word: "sixteen" },
     { id: 17, word: "seventeen" },
     { id: 18, word: "eighteen" }
  ];





const initialState = {
    tid: 0, //target[0]?.id,
    name: "A" //target[0]?.word
  };




const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const [raw, setRaw] = useState(initialState);



 useEffect ( () => {
    setRaw((raw) => ({ ...raw, tid: target[count]?.id }));
    setRaw((raw) => ({ ...raw, name: target[count].word }));
  }, [count])


  function change() {
    console.log(raw); //axios function to insert record
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={change}>Click</h1>
      <h2>Count : {count}</h2>
      <h2>
        Array: {target[count]?.id}{target[count].word}
      </h2>
      <h2>
        State Object : {raw.tid},{raw.name}
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```